# Access to the path Log is denied randomly

Tags: vb.net

when I write to my log file I sometimes get access to log path is denied C:/app/log.log

Here is my code:

```
Private filePath As String
Private fileStream As FileStream
Private streamWriter As StreamWriter

Public Sub OpenFile()
    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "\log.log"
    If System.IO.File.Exists(strPath) Then
        fileStream = New FileStream(strPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
    Else
        fileStream = New FileStream(strPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    End If
    streamWriter = New StreamWriter(fileStream)
End Sub

Public Sub WriteLog(ByVal strComments As String)
    OpenFile()
    streamWriter.WriteLine(Date.Now.ToString & " " & strComments)
    CloseFile()
End Sub

Public Sub CloseFile()
    streamWriter.Close()
    fileStream.Close()
End Sub
```

Is there anyway to make this use admin permissions or fix this issue? It only happens sometimes, and I'm not sure why it happens, but if I delete the log.log file the application can write to log again.  Very weird.

Comment: If it works *sometimes*, it is probably not a permissions issue, but rather an "in use" issue. I'm surprised you're not having permissions issues. Applications should not be able to write to a root directory of the C:\ drive. Write log files into AppData instead.

Comment: Since you create a new filestream everytime you write to it, why do you also have it as a public variable that is never disposed?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your function `WriteLog` from multiple threads asynchronously, you should protect this function for example with a mutex.

Comment: You think that's the reason? How would I do this?